# Ensure the font size for captions of figures and tables

Tags: ieeetran, ieee-style

A reviewer says that I have to ensure that

```
Captions of figures and tables: Font size should be 8 point.
```

Is there anyway I can ensure this? As I can't tell what is the size that I am currently using, thanks.

Here's the preamble

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
 \usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, url, proof} % mathabx,
\usepackage[
        colorlinks=true,
        citecolor=black,
        linkcolor=black,
        urlcolor=black,
        ]{hyperref}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{csp}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{tikz}
%add usepackage%
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono}
\usepackage[skip=2pt]{caption}
\lstset{language=XML,
numberstyle=\footnotesize,
basicstyle=\footnotesize,
numbers=left,
stepnumber=1,
frame=shadowbox,
breaklines=true}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\sq}{\square}
```

Comment: I'd regard this as a bizarre request if you're required to use the IEEEtran class. Can you add a minimal example of your preamble?

Comment: Why do you manually need to control the font size? Please download the whole bunch from http://www.ieee.org/publications_standards/publications/authors/author_templates.html or http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/ and take a look at the templates.

Comment: @egreg I have edited to include the preamble, is there away to print out the size of figures and tables that i am currently using?

Comment: @MMA I am aware of that, I am thinking maybe the reviewer are thinking I am not using the default font I guess, therefore  am curious is there a way to print out the font size of caption for figures and tables that I am using

Comment: @william007 Please, add also the `\documentclass` line

Comment: @egreg I have edited the question with that

Answer (score 11):

The problem is in your usage of the `caption` package. Remove it, because it's not really compatible with `IEEEtran` and it's responsible for the change from the standard font size of captions.

There are some other glitches in your code:

1. the package `times` shouldn't be loaded, as it's the default for IEEEtran
2. the package `epsfig` is obsolete and should never be used in new documents
3. the package `hyperref` should be loaded *last* (there are some packages that must go after it, but you use none of them)
4. finally, the `csp` package seems not to be standard (it's not in TeX Live, for instance); if it's what I found on the net, it should be loaded with the `[times]` option.

Comment: you are right, the caption package is the culprit, I am adding it to cater for the line break, for details see the attached url, is it possible to get rid of the caption package in this case?:http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101595/how-to-add-line-break-to-caption-without-using-caption-package

Comment: @william007 I'd simply avoid explicit line breaks that the IEEEtran style doesn't allow. A line break might be substituted by a dash `---`, for instance.