# How to add line break to caption without using caption package

Tags: line-breaking, captions

I wish to add a line break to a caption, but I would wish to avoid adding of `caption` package. Is it possible?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[format=plain, 
justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{This is the caption\\ This is the second line}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use `caption` package?

Comment: @hpesoj626 it's related to this question:http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101424/ensure-the-font-size-for-captions-of-figures-and-tables

Comment: Unless you specifically need a _linebreak_ I suggest you make _two paragraphs_ by adding a blank line.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption[caption]{This is the caption\\\hspace{\textwidth}This is the second line}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The reason why `\\` does not work originally is that the caption is small enough to fit on one line. The default caption setting first sets the caption in an mbox and if that is less than the line width that box is centred. Otherwise that box is discarded and the caption is re-set in a parbox. On the first setting `\\` does nothing as it is always a no-op in such a box, on the second setting (if it is used)  then `\\` starts a new line. So all you have to do is make sure that the first setting is not used, as the space at the start of a line is discarded, it doesn't really matter how big the space is, so long as the total natural width of the whole caption is bigger than `\textwidth`.

Comment: I think the `\\\` can be omitted?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides no see comment to Hendrick (it sort of works in this case but you get an overfull box) but in general you need `\\ ` as the setting is not raggedright by default)

Comment: @David: Wow, great explanation, thank you very much!

Comment: In an Overleaf document I was unable to include \\, but the hspace worked nicely. It used IEEEtran.cls (packages [utf8]inputenc, framed, booktabs, hyperref, wrapfig, tikz, todonotes, regexpatch, xcolor, listings). The error was: `Argument of \Hy@tempa has an extra }. <inserted text> \par l.631 ...`.

Comment: Nice answer. I defined a new command like so ``\newcommand\nextline{\\*\hspace{\textwidth}}`` with the star version of ``\\*`` to prevent a new page. Reasonable?

Comment: You can't have a new page in a figure, so the `*` is harmless but not needed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle if I remove the optional argument `[caption]`, the mwe above fails when compiled with `make4ht` with textlive 2023 (as of today).

Comment: @MatteoGamboz you would need the option anyway as you dont normally force line breaks in lof

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, thanks. I've reported it here https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/index.php?599 (just in case :)

Answer (score 15):

The problem with using `\\` in `\caption{..}` (a single mandatory argument) is that this defaults to `\caption[..]{..}` (optional + mandatory), and `\\` is problematic in the optional argument. If you specify an alternative non-`\\` optional argument, then it's okay, but `\\` is made "useless" or has no effect. You could use a `tabular` to set the argument:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \caption[This is the caption; This is the second line]
    {\tabular[t]{@{}l@{}}This is the caption \\ This is the second line\endtabular}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Of course, if you don't need the optional argument (since you might not be using a `\listoftables`), just use an empty optional argument. Without more context of the requirement, I'm not sure how useful it might be.

Comment: I think this is the prettiest option.

Answer (score 10):

Not sure why, but a `\protect\linebreak` works in the `boxhandler` package, but not in the `\caption` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{boxhandler}
\begin{document}

\bxfigure{Caption goes \protect\linebreak here}
{\fbox{Goodbye, very, very, very cruel world}}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\fbox{Goodbye, very, very, very cruel world}
\caption{Caption goes \protect\linebreak here}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

One alternative is a `minipage` with `\\` in the long caption. Note that in this way, the sort caption (between `[]`) is not longer optional but as mandatory argument. If you want also a line break in the list of figures, simply use a  `\newline` in the sort caption:

Edit: As Werner noted, the width of `minipage` must be  less than `\linewidth` to avoid problems (now corrected in the MWE) or use `varwidth` package)

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \caption
  [This is the caption \newline This is the second line]
  {\begin{minipage}[t]{.8\linewidth}This is the caption \\This is the second line \end{minipage}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This probably was accompanied by a bad box...

Comment: @Werner, what do you mean by "bad box" is the "Overfull \hbox" warning? How dangerous is it really?

Comment: Since you're setting the contents in a box, if the figure name + number + first line of caption > `\textwidth`, it will spill over the margin *visually*. While that may never happen, the box will necessarily push the caption to the left (always) because of its size. In this instance it would be better to use [`varwidth`](http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth).

Comment: As usual you're right. Funnily, I really did a first draft with `varwidth`, but then I thought that if he wanted a solution without `caption` package, he would not want a solution using another package and tested that original `minipage` worked also in the MWE.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can use `\protect\linebreak`, also without `caption` package.

For a short caption text, it works the same as `\\\hspace{\textwidth}`. However, it can be a better solution, **if your caption text is longer** and without the line break would occupy more than one line and **you want it to be stretched to fill the line**.

Example:

```latex
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \caption[caption]{This is the first line of a caption text that \\\hspace{\textwidth} without the
      linebreak would occupy more than one line and it goes and it goes}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
    \caption{This is the first line of a caption text that \protect\linebreak without the
      linebreak would occupy more than one line and it goes and it goes}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

[image: figure1]
[image: figure2]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Do you use the... `caption` package in your first example?

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the code for first example (`\\\hspace..` instead of "\\"), so that it works without `caption` package.