# position caption of centered figure left-adjusted to figure

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, captions

I have a problem with the alignment of the caption of an image. 
My image is centered and I need the caption to be left-adjusted relative to my image like that:

```
                    -------------------
                    |                 |          
                    |      image      |
                    -------------------
                    Figure 1: my image
                    Source:
```

I tried the caption package with:

```
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize, justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}
```

Code to load figure:

```
\begin{figure}[htpb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width = 10cm]{Zeichnungsverfahren.png}  
  \caption[caption]{This is the caption}  
  \label{fig:zeichnungsverfahren2}
\end{figure}
```

but it clearly didn't work.

It gave me something like this:

```
                    -------------------
                    |                 |          
                    |      image      |
                    -------------------
Figure 1: my image

Source:
```

I'm new with Latex so I hope you can help me out.?
Greets Tony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a yet not documented macro called `\captionbox` in the [caption](https://ctan.org/pkg/caption) package which should do what you want.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup{
  font=footnotesize,
  justification=raggedright,
  singlelinecheck=false
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \captionbox{Caption\label{fig:dummy}}{%
      \rule{8cm}{4.5cm}
    }
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The syntax of this command is identical to `\subcaptionbox`, which is described in Section 4 of the [subcaption](https://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) manual.

Note that the caption will now no longer exceed the width of the object at both sides.

---

[image]

---

**Update**

According to the comment this is an example with a new line for the source of the figure.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup{
  font=footnotesize,
  justification=raggedright,
  singlelinecheck=false
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \captionbox[Caption]{Caption\par Source:\label{fig:dummy}}{%
      \rule{8cm}{4.5cm}
    }
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: By the way, the »[floatrow](http://ctan.org/pkg/floatrow)« package offers a similar command.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer! Your code does not compile in with my system. "Undefined Control Sequence" in the line with "\captionbox.." . Could it be that I have a version of the caption package which is too old?

Comment: @Tony: Make sure that your version of »[caption](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption)« is up to date. Current version is v3.3-89 from 2013/05/02. Do an update of your TeX system.

Comment: Thank you very much! I updated texlive and your code works now wonderfully! There is one other little thing, I hope it is ok when I write it right here. I need another line in the caption, I updated it above in my example. I found this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101595/how-to-add-line-break-to-caption-without-using-caption-package but it didn't work.

Comment: @Tony: See the update.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs the same anytime, the following code should solve.

```
\begin{figure}[htpb]
   \centering
    \captionbox[Text]{Zehcninasddwqe \label{fig:dummy}\subcaption*{Source: www...}}{%
     \includegraphics[width = 10cm]{zeichnen.png}  
    }   
 \end{figure}
```