# Missing \item when putting image in beamer

Tags: captions, line-breaking

I attach my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Frame title}

  \begin{figure}[!htp]
    \includegraphics[height=0.5\textheight]{example-image}
    \caption{\center \textbf{Title} \\
      some more caption stuff\ldots}
  \end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Why do I get an error: `! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.` for this one?

Comment: If your main aim is to insert a line-break inside the `\caption`, then this question is a duplicate of [How to add line break to caption without using `caption` package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/101595/5764). In your case, you can use `\caption{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}} \bfseries ... \\ ... \end{tabular}}`.

Comment: Also, don't use `\center` in the `\caption`.

Comment: What exactly do you hope `[!htp]` will do on a *slide*?

Comment: Perhaps `\def\caption{}`? I assume that you are copying materials from a long document and you do not want to modify the contents too much. But after all you do not need a "**Figure**" prompt. Nor do you need a readable `\listoffigures`. So `\caption` here brings you nothing but pain... am I right?