# Subtitle in table

Tags: tables, notes

I have a table of the form

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} % 
\begin{document}    
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\caption{\centering How many people \\
 \scriptsize     Average over a thousand simulations}
\label{table1}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
 $r \backslash 2n$  & 100 & 200& 1000\\
 \hline\\
 2 & 25.42 & 25.76 &25.47\\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \end{center}
 \end{table}
\end{document}
```

My question is that here I have a nice subtitle, that looks great but that gives me errors when running it. Is there a way to take away the errors but make it look exactly the same? I really don't like \tablenotes.

EDIT: the error I am getting is

```
 Argument of \caption @ydblarg has an extra }
```

Comment: Which errors do you mean? Could you provide a complete MWE that we can compile?

Comment: Argument of \caption @ydblarg has an extra }.

Comment: Does [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101595/how-to-add-line-break-to-caption-without-using-caption-package) help?

Comment: @Karlo: I also just looked at this, and gave me the idea to use the `caption` package. So: does `\usepackage{caption}` in the preamble and then `\caption{How many people\\ \scriptsize Average over a thousand simulations}` produce what you want? I don't think the `\centering` is needed then, because the default of the `caption` package is to center anyway for short captions

Comment: I am using the caption package. The answer suggestion works fine, but the title is still aligned to the left. When I write \centering, the error produces

Comment: "Something is wrong, perhaps a missing item"

Comment: Done: \usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}

Comment: The problem is in the \\ after "How many people". You should try this solution:https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101595/how-to-add-line-break-to-caption-without-using-caption-package

Answer (score 3):

So, by loading the `caption` package, I obtain a solution:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} % 
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}    
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{ How many people \\ 
\scriptsize  Average over a thousand simulations}
\label{table1}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
 $r \backslash 2n$  & 100 & 200& 1000\\
 \hline\\
 2 & 25.42 & 25.76 &25.47\\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]