# Why does caption throw an error?

Tags: captions

I used the solution from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101624/137734) which works kind of but throws an error:

> pdflatex> ! Argument of \@caption has an extra }.
>   ...
>   pdflatex> ! Paragraph ended brfore \@caption was complete.

Here is a reproducible example - If you load any picture, there are still the two errors above:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{a4wide,german,fancyhdr}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\begin{document}

text before

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  %\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{path2/figure.png}
  \caption{first line\\\hspace{\textwidth} Second line.}
\end{figure}

text after

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, note that `german.sty` is obsolete; do `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` instead. The `a4wide` package has been deprecated for several years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\\` is sort of a fragile command.  When written to the aux file it is expanded multiple times, resulting in an error.  Prefix `\\` with `\protect` and the error goes away.  Even better though, don't use line breaks in the caption, it doesn't look nice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

text before

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{first line\protect\\\hspace{\textwidth} Second line.}
\end{figure}

text after

\end{document}
```

Comment: Good point with extra line. But I would like to include a reference "http.//..." and this is more than one line...